# Dynamically get docker version during image build

Tags: docker

I'm working on a project the requires me to run docker within docker. Currently, I am just relying on the docker client to be running within docker and passing in an environment variable to the TCP address of the docker daemon with which I want to communicate.

The file in the Dockerfile that I use to install the client looks like this:

`RUN curl -s https://get.docker.io/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest -o /usr/local/bin/docker`

However, the problem is that this will always download the latest docker version. Ideally, I will always have the Docker instance running this container on the latest version, but occasionally it may be a version behind (for example I haven't yet upgraded from 1.2 to 1.3). What I really want is a way to dynamically get the version of the Docker instance that's building this Dockerfile, and then pass that in to the URL to download the appropriate version of Docker. Is this at all possible? The only thing I can think of is to have an `ENV` command at the top of the Dockerfile, which I need to manually set, but ideally I was hoping that it could be set dynamically based on the actual version of the Docker instance.

Answer (score 0):

While your question makes sense from an engineering point of view, it is at odds with the intention of the Dockerfile. If the build process depended on the environment, it would not be reproducible elsewhere.  There is not a convenient way to achieve what you ask.